# Hover Over Question

Tags: carto, infowindow

I'm very new to this and don't understand much, however I've created this map:https://muscbaker.cartodb.com/viz/2407e742-938a-11e5-a195-0ecd1babdde5/public_map and selected for the name and description to appear when hovered over. In my editing screen, the hover over icon appears - however when I go to publish, nothing happens. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you added the infowindow on the data view 'map', not the published map.

After you import data and then click 'visualize', make sure that you add hover to the infowindow on the published map. If you only add the infowindow on the 'map' that is associated with the data view, it won't show on the published map.

It's confusing as there is a data and map view for 'datasets' and also a data and map view for 'maps'.